# Datatables the Angular Way using Get instead of Post

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

The docs show using an Http Post to get the data for Angular Datatables but I would prefer to do a Get.  Is this possible?  I haven't found any examples and changing to .get and removing the third parameter results in the page completely failing to load.

Sample from docs:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

class Person {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

class DataTablesResponse {
  data: any[];
  draw: number;
  recordsFiltered: number;
  recordsTotal: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-side-angular-way',
  templateUrl: 'server-side-angular-way.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['server-side-angular-way.component.css']
})
export class ServerSideAngularWayComponent implements OnInit {
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  persons: Person[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const that = this;

    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 2,
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
        that.http
          .post<DataTablesResponse>(
            'https://angular-datatables-demo-server.herokuapp.com/',
            dataTablesParameters, {}
          ).subscribe(resp => {
            that.persons = resp.data;

            callback({
              recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
              recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
              data: []
            });
          });
      },
      columns: [{ data: 'id' }, { data: 'firstName' }, { data: 'lastName' }]
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Why are you using a closure ? You don't have any scope issues
2. That's a demo server, they probably simply made a mistake
3. After trying to paste the URL in my browser, I got the data, so yes, you can make a GET request.

Comment: I'm trying to learn this so not sure where the closure is, not seeing that.  This is the EXACT code they tell you to use on their site.  It works for me as a post but not as a get.  Is this code bad?

Comment: `var that = this` → you don't need this line, you won't lose your `this` context by declaring an object.

Comment: The request also works into Postman FYI @ConnieDeCinko. And please people, have some common sense and comment when you downvote.